# I want to add a button to the <AutocompleteInput> list

Tags: react-admin

I want to add a "create new" button at the top of the  list.

Similar to what has been implemented in this tutorial: https://marmelab.com/blog/2018/08/27/react-admin-tutorials-custom-forms-related-records.html

Except I would like the create button to be the first item/button in the list.

**UPDATE**

This is as far as I have gotten:

[image]

It still isn't apart of the list, and it does not perform the way I want it to. When the create button is pressed nothing happens, except the list closes. A modal should appear like in the tutorial linked above.

```
    renderSuggestionsContainer = autosuggestOptions => {
    const {
        containerProps: { className, ...containerProps },
        children,
    } = autosuggestOptions;
    const { classes = {}, options } = this.props;

    // Force the Popper component to reposition the popup only when this.inputEl is moved to another location
    this.updateAnchorEl();

    return (
        <>
        <Popper
            className={className}
            open={Boolean(children)}
            anchorEl={this.anchorEl}
            placement="bottom-start"
            {...options.suggestionsContainerProps}
        >
            <PostQuickCreateButtton id={1} reference="post"
                                                        perPage={100}
                                                        label="">
            </PostQuickCreateButtton>
            <Paper
                square
                className={classes.suggestionsPaper}
                {...containerProps}
            >
                {children}
            </Paper>
        </Popper>
        </>
    );
};
```

Comment: And where is your current code?

Comment: I do not have any code at the moment. I'm currently looking for the source code for the react-admin <SelectInput> component to try and implement a prototype.